# Bootstrap 4 Beta: Options Menu has double dropdown icons

Tags: html, css, gulp, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have an issue with the way Bootstrap makes my options menu visualize. Check out the screenshot:

[image]

I don't know what is the reason for this. I am not using labels in this particular case but they don't help either.

This is the code:

```
        <nav class="sidebar col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-inline align-self-auto">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="custom-select mt-2">
                <option selected>Марка</option>
                <option value="1">БМВ</option>
                <option value="2">Рено</option>
                <option value="3">Форд</option>
            </select>
```

Please help me with this one as I want a great looking website.
I am using Bootstrap 4.0.0.b
I should also mention I am using gulp to compile my CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the following css, however bootstrap should already take care of that. How do you see the same select on bootstrap's website? Does it have double arrow there as well? What browser are you using?

```
.custom-select{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

### Edit:

Be careful when using the above solution. These CSS properties are already present in [bootstrap.min.css](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css) and the Custom Select renders fine on their demo: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/#custom-select

[image]

Make sure you are using the proper version and there's nothing overwriting Bootstrap's CSS.

Comment: This fixed it. Although I consider it more of a work around. The issue appeared when I moved from the CDN to a "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.3" collected with npm. I am using Mozilla Firefox 52.5.2 on Debian.

Comment: By the way I wanted to try not using beta.3 and install beta only. And it was worse affecting button colouring and options menu width. I hope these issues will be fixed in customer.

Comment: Sass files from the Bootstrap source don't include the vendor prefixes. A tool like Autoprefixer is needed to add them a build time. [Related doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/#source-files)

Comment: Still get this issue at Bootstrap 4.1.1. Unbelievable! Thank you.

Comment: Still presented in 4.2.1, omfg

Comment: @Andrey please check my edit. It could be something on your end.

Answer (score 0):

If it's dropdown menu you are looking for, everything is here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

If you are looking for something else, also everything is there, in documentation, with code and examples :)

Normal side-menu templates https://bootsnipp.com/tags/sidebar

Comment: Hi, It's an options element as described here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/ I want to keep it as an options item as this is what it is. I don't want to use dropdowns in this case as there might be many alements in the list and it does not look suitable..

Answer (score 0):

Removing the link to Bootstrap CDN worked for me. Try to remove the Bootstrap CDN link.